# Summing column_property values

Tags: sql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have two `column_property` columns that I'd like to sum together in the `grandtotal` column.  I want to be able to sort and filter against the `grandtotal` column.

How can I sum the `subtotal` and `shipping` columns' values?

Code:

```
subtotal = orm.column_property(
    select([case(
        [(func.sum(OrderProductModel.subtotal).is_(None), 0)],
        else_=func.sum(OrderProductModel.subtotal))
    ]).where(OrderProductModel.order_id == id))
shipping = orm.column_property(case(
    [(is_expedited.is_(True), shipping_rate)], else_=Decimal(0.00)))
grandtotal = orm.column_property(func.sum(subtotal + shipping))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ColumnProperty' and 'ColumnProperty'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to summing [expressions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.ColumnProperty.expression) of this column properties

```
grandtotal = orm.column_property(func.sum(subtotal.expression + shipping.expression))
```

Comment: Thanks bud!  I also had to group the `grandtotal` `column_property` by the order id.  `grandtotal = orm.column_property(select([func.sum(subtotal.expression + shipping.expression)]).group_by(id))`